# Hierarchy label customization - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a Clustered column chart in Power BI which has a category and date on the Axis so that there's a hierarchy to view the data on. In the hierarchy view, each column in the chart has the full hierarchy name below it. I would like to have the category name once only and then the dates for each column specified instead of the dates and category name with each date repeated. So I would like for the hierarchy labels to have their own "grouping" as it were. Is anyone able to assist with this please? I don't want to pivot the data because then there's a legend that viewers of the report need to look at to see what color column matches up to which date in the chart which isn't practical.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone does run into this I ended up using the Infographic Designer custom visual that I imported from the Power BI Marketplace. With this I was able to achieve what I wanted by using the "Column By" feature of the visual. This gave me multiple charts for the different groups of data I wanted to view.